# Count number of overlapping items in two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, of which the `Remove` should be removed from the `List`, and the number removed should be counted.

I'm using this to remove those from `'Remove'`:

```
  let output=this.List.filter((el)=>{
    return this.Remove.indexOf(el) <0;
  })
```

This is working fine, but I'd like to count the number of items that have overlapped, and thus been removed in the filter.

For example, if `List=['1','2','3','4','5']` and `Remove=['1','4']`, `count` would be `2`.

Many thanks!

Comment: This might be overly simplistic, but why not compare the `length` before and after?

Comment: Just compare the list length before and after removing, then find that difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one `reduce` run. For example, you can create an object and track both cleared array and a number of deleted elements:

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
const b = [1,4,9]; // elements to remove

const c = a.reduce((acc, cur) => b.includes(cur) 
  ? Object.assign(acc, {n: acc.n + 1}) 
  : Object.assign(acc, {res: acc.res.concat(cur)}), { n: 0, res: []});
  
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to compare lengths as suggested in comments (which is fine...), I can propose you the following solution using a counter:

```js
let list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    remove = ['1', '4'],
    overlap = 0;

let output = list.filter(el => {
  let bool = remove.indexOf(el) < 0;
  if (!bool) overlap++;
  return bool;
});

console.log(overlap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the items in the arrays `a` and `b` are unique, you can make use of Sets to get the absolute number of intersections as a one-liner:

```
const a = [1,2,3,4];
const b = [2,4,5];
const overlap = a.length + b.length - new Set(a.concat(b)).size; // => 2
```